# return null row in mysql if record not found for the given id

Tags: mysql, ifnull

Hi am using the below mysql query

```
SELECT *
         FROM particulars pp
        WHERE (pp.SnoFK IN (108,999999)
               AND pp.curMonth = STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

In my table i have record for only 108, so it returns **only one row** for 108.

Is there any other option in mysql that can i return two rows which i dont have the id in the table like

1.108 | *

2.999999 | null values

Answer (score 3):

I have no better idea:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82cc5/2

```
SELECT
  ids.id,
  particulars.*
FROM (  SELECT 108    AS id
  UNION SELECT 1122   AS id
  UNION SELECT 999999 AS id
  ) AS ids -- create a "table" with the required numbers
LEFT JOIN particulars ON particulars.SnoFK = ids.id
```